# Type conversion in elasticsearch scripts

Tags: scripting, elasticsearch, mvel

I would like to use a script to do the following:

```
{
  "query": {
  "match_all": {}
},
  "facets": {
    "user_facet": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "script": "term + \"_\" + _source.code"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is similar to the answer given in this question:
[elastic search double facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211732/elastic-search-double-facet)

The only problem I have is my user_id and code fields are long types, rather than strings.  Is there a way to make them strings so they can be combined with the script?

The particular error I am getting is this:

```
nested: ClassCastException[java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number];
```

Comment: I don't see from your example how a long user_id can ever match the term that you are calculating in the script, which is a sting, even if you did convert it. I must be missing something.

Comment: One thought to try... Maybe using `doc['user_id']` for the field would work?

Comment: You can use Java within an mvel script too. I would just convert them to Strings using java then ;)

Answer (score 3):

This might sound ridiculous, but I had the same issue, and the way I fixed it (for a VERY similar problems) was to drop the "field" specification so that it looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
  "match_all": {}
},
  "facets": {
    "user_facet": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "term + \"_\" + _source.code"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think it was trying to convert the output of the "script" execution back into the type of the field, causing the class cast exception.